# JQuery timepicker options on updatepanel postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, timepicker

I have using this jquery addon:

http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

Dynamically I am trying to get a line of code that corresponds to OnHourShowCallback function called by the event onHourShow. The goal is to change this line of code dynamically according to the option selected in DropDownList and a specific date that the user selects. All this for times available according to the selected office (DropDownList).

Initially this line of code is empty, as is until the user selects an office and indicates the date, time schedules are displayed in the timepicker, HOWEVER after the postback the code line continues empty. I tried ASP.NET function that returns this line, manually sending parameters and returns the correct data.

This is my Js code in head section:

```
function prepareScripts() {
    $('#<%=Me.txtHrSalX.ClientID%>').timepicker({
        onHourShow: OnHourShowCallback
    });

    function OnHourShowCallback(hour) { <%= getHoursByOffice(Me.DropDownOffice.SelectedValue, Me.txtDate.Text) %>
        //if ((hour == 14 || hour == 15) || (hour > 20) || (hour < 6)) { return false; } // This is the dynamic line that I am trying to get
        return true; // valid
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    prepareScripts()
});
```

This is the ASP.Net Code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "JQuery", "prepareScripts();", True)

End Sub

Public Function getHoursByOffice(ByVal strOffice As String, ByVal strDate As Date) As String

...

End Function
```

I want to mention that I have on the same page datepicker JQuery and works perfectly even with the updatepanel postback . The problem is not that JQuery function inside the update panel , the problem is that I can not change this setting in particular (dynamic line in OnHourShowCallback ) timepicker addon to do postback in update panel .

Thanks for any help in this regard.